# zgrep for multiple pipe symbols in a bunch of gz files

Tags: linux, grep, pipe, zgrep

I have a lot of .gz files in a folder

```
/a/b/c1.gz
/a/b/c2.gz
/a/b/c3.gz
```

and so on.

Some of the files have a single pipe delimiter, some have two, three and four and so on, in such a way:

```
xyz|abc
xyz|abc|wty
xyz|abc|wty|asd
```

and so on.

How do I find all the files that have two pipe delimiters overall, three delimiters overall etc ?

Comment: thank you @steeldriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create three test files:

```
echo 'xyz|abc' > c1
echo 'xyz|abc|wty' > c2
echo 'xyz|abc|wty|asd' > c3
gzip c*
```

---

Files containing one pipe in a line:

```
$ zgrep '^[^|]*|[^|]*$' *.gz
c1.gz:xyz|abc
```

---

For any other numbers (including one pipe in a line), you can use the following pattern:

Two pipes in a line:

```
$ zgrep -E '^([^|]*\|){2}[^|]*$' *.gz
c2.gz:xyz|abc|wty
```

Three pipes in a line:

```
$ zgrep -E '^([^|]*\|){3}[^|]*$' *.gz
c3.gz:xyz|abc|wty|asd
```

Two or three pipes in a line:

```
$ zgrep -E '^([^|]*\|){2,3}[^|]*$' *.gz
c2.gz:xyz|abc|wty
c3.gz:xyz|abc|wty|asd
```

Max. three pipes in a line:

```
$ zgrep -E '^([^|]*\|){,3}[^|]*$' *.gz
c1.gz:xyz|abc
c2.gz:xyz|abc|wty
c3.gz:xyz|abc|wty|asd
```

If you only need the filename, add option `-l`, i.e. `zgrep -lE ...`

---

My `zgrep` version doesn't support the recursive `-r` option.

You could use `find` for a recusive search and run `zgrep` on the result:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.gz' -exec zgrep -lE '^([^|]*\|){3}[^|]*$' {} \;
./c3.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in any given file, the number of `|`-delimited columns is constant, then it's enough to inspect the first line of a file to determine the number of columns in it.

The following will do that for a file called `name.gz`:

```
gzip -dc name.gz | awk -F '|' -v name="name.gz" '{ print NF, name } { exit }'
```

So, with a simple loop, you would be able to output the number of columns and the filenames of, e.g., all files matching the pattern `/a/b/c*.gz`:

```sh
for name in /a/b/c*.gz; do
    gzip -dc "$name" |
    awk -F '|' -v name="$name" '{ print NF, name } { exit }'
done
```

If you want to only output the names of the files with a certain number of columns (`n=3`, for example), then use

```sh
n=3
for name in /a/b/c*.gz; do
    gzip -dc "$name" |
    awk -F '|' -v n="$n" -v name="$name" 'NF == n { print name } { exit }'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe file names to awk and find number of |-s in each.  For example:
echo 'A|B|C' |awk -F\| '{print NF-1}'